# Gridster.js: Prevent dragging on clickable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, gridster

I am using Gridster in a project. My scenario is:

I have a series of blocks in a gridster grid, and the problem I am facing, is that I don't want all of the blocks to be draggable. I have tried setting the `ignore_dragging` callback, and I have successfully stopped those blocks from being draggable, but I cannot use this as it also prevents normally click events from getting through.

I also tried doing `event.preventDefault()` in the `start` and `drag` event callbacks, but that proved ineffective.

Is there another way of cancelling dragging on some blocks, but allowing click events to pass?

Thanks in very much.